# como mandar una variable con ajax a otra pagina php para generar una consulta

Tags: php, ajax

tengo un select option que lleno con la BD quiero que al elegir una opción obtener su id para luego enviarlo a otra pagina php para colocarlo en una consulta select para traer datos y colocarlos en una tabla todo esto con ajax sin recargar la pagina.

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PARA GENERAR EL SELECT ESTA EN UNA PAGINA LLAMADA HISTORIAL.PHP:

```
    <select  name="conductor" id="conductor" class="form-control" onchange="pdf()">
    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <?php
    $query1="SELECT  * FROM conductor";
    $result1=mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die (mysqli_error());
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id_conductor'].'">'.$row['nombre'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onchange="pdf()">Responsiva</button>
```

ASI INTENTO MANDAR MIS DATOS ESTE CODIGO ESTA EN LA PAGINA HISTORIAL.PHP TAMBIEN

```
function pdf(){
conductor =$("#conductor").val();
$.ajax({
url:"cartaresponsiva.php",
type: "POST",
data: {condutor: conductor},
success: function(respuesta){
}
});
}
```

Y AQUI TENGO UNA TABLA ES DONDE QUIERO PONER MIS DATOS QUE RECOJA DESPUES DE LA CONSULTA ESTA EN OTRA PAGINA LLAMADA CARTARESPONSIVA.PHP

```
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th class="no">#</th>
 <th class="desc">Nombre</th>
 <th class="unit">Vehículo</th>
 <th class="qty">Fecha de Reasignación</th>           
 </tr>
 </thead>
    <?php
    $conductor=$_POST['conductor'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

    $query="SELECT  id_conductor,nombre,vehiculo,fecha_modificacion FROM conductor  WHERE id_conductor  = ' " . $conductor. " ' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

      echo "<tbody>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td class='no'>".$row['id_conductor']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='desc'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='unit'>".$row['vehiculo']."</td>"; 
      echo "<td class='qty'>".$row['fecha_modificacion']."</td>";   
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</tbody>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Problemas al llamar tabla".mysqli_error());

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: has visto que llega aqui: `$conductor=$_POST['conductor'];`

Comment: selecciono mi item del select option doy clic en el boton para ejecutar mi funcion pdf pero en la pagina donde tengo mi consulta no genera nada

Comment: puedes hacer un var_dump($conductor);exit() para que que recibe esa variable

Comment: ya logre obtener el id en la variable pero no se como estructurar mi consulta dentro de la tabla para mostrar los datos que recogeré de la BD con la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo algunas cosas que creo te están generando el error.

Empecemos con tu `select` del HTML, el que ya tiene las opciones con `PHP`:

```
<select  name="conductor" id="conductor" class="form-control" onchange="pdf(this)">
<option value="">Seleccione...</option>
<?php
$query1="SELECT  * FROM conductor";
$result1=mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die (mysqli_error());
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
echo '<option value="'.$row['id_conductor'].'">'.$row['nombre'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Aquí no deberías agregar un evento `.onChange()` al **boton**, ya que dices que la funcionalidad la necesitas es con el `select`, además que el `onChange` no es un evento natural de los botónes.

Agregué como parámetro a la función `pdf()` la palabra reservada `this`, con el fin de referirnos a el `select` cuando queramos obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada.

Ahora, aquí en tu función `pdf()` debe quedar así:

```
function pdf(element){
  conductor = element.val();
  $.ajax({
   url:"cartaresponsiva.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {condutor: conductor},
   success: function(respuesta){
     //Aquí debes cargar (respuesta) a tu <table>
     $("#idTable").html(respuesta);
   }
  });
}
```

Aquí noté un error de digitación, pues en `data` tienes **condutor** en lugar de condu**c**tor, y ví que en el PHP lo resives como **conductor**

En el `succes` debes cargar la respuesta a tu `<table>` que deberías tener algo como `<table id="idTable">  </table>`, para que los registros aparezcan cargándolos así: `$("#idTable").html(respuesta);`

Y por último, en tu **PHP**, lo único no me parece correcto es que tengas el código `HTML` de la tabla donde pretendes cargar los registros, para eso, opino que es mejor dejarlo en el HTML, lo único que debes imprimir en `echo` debe ser el HTML del `<tbody>`, es decir, así:

`

```
$query="SELECT  id_conductor,nombre,vehiculo,fecha_modificacion FROM conductor  WHERE id_conductor  = ' " . $conductor. " ' ";
echo "<tbody>";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='no'>".$row['id_conductor']."</td>";
  echo "<td class='desc'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
  echo "<td class='unit'>".$row['vehiculo']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td class='qty'>".$row['fecha_modificacion']."</td>";   
  echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</tbody>";

mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Problemas al llamar tabla".mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

Y deja los `echo` que abren y cierran el `<tbody>` fuera del ciclo `while`.

Espero haberte ayudado en algo, y espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: lo unico que no entendí es : En el succes debes cargar la respuesta a tu <table> que deberías tener algo como <table id="idTable">  </table>, para que los registros aparezcan cargándolos así: $("#idTable").html(respuesta);

Comment: que respuesta debo de dar en mi success ahi hago la otra parte de la tabla en html o como ? y el tbody lo genero en mi php donde tengo la consulta ?

Comment: Exacto, es decir, en el PHP, tienes los `echo` con el `<tbody>` y sus respectivos `<tr>`, ahora, en el HTML la estructura d ela tabla debe ser así: `<table><thead><tr><td>etc...</td></tr></thead><tbody id="idTable"></tbody></table>`, Y en el succes colocas `$("#idTable").html(respuesta);`    Otra cosa, quita los `echo` de los `<tbody>`, el que abre y cierra la etiqueta

Comment: ok perfecto ya funciono muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ok @jasieltorres, me alegro haber podido ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer no estas obteniendo el valor del elemento conductor
intente obtenerlo por su id con ("#conductor").val()

ejemplo:

```
$(document).on('change', '#conductor', function(event){
       var conductor =parseInt($(this).find("option:selected")).val());
       //otra opcion, parseInt($("#conductor option:selected").val());
       $.ajax({
         url:"cartaresponsiva.php",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {condutor: conductor},
          success: function(respuesta){
           $("#id_table").html(respuesta.result);
         }
       });
    })
```

en php

```
$html="";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $html.="<tr><td>".$row["id_conductor"]."</td><td>".$row["nombre"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=> $html));
```

espero que sea esto.

Comment: ya logre obtener el id pero no se como estructurar mi consulta dentro de la tabla para mostrar los datos que recogeré de la BD con la consulta

Comment: <tbody>
  <tr>    
  <td class="no"></td>
  <td class="desc"></td>   
  <td class="unit"></td>
   <td class="qty"></td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>

Comment: no estoy total mente perdido no se donde llamar a mi funcion pdf por que antes de llamarla tengo que selecccionar un item del select option y para ello utilizo un onchange